# Why is virtualenv not setting my terminal prompt?

Tags: bash, virtualenv

I have virtualenv running on Mac OSX (10.8.2), and whilst it works (I can set up venvs, switch between them, activate and deactvate), the one thing that doesn't work (and is quite annoying) is the terminal prompt switch.

My basic prompt is `[\u] \w \n\[\033[0;31m\]$\[\e[0m\]`, which renders as:

```
[hugo] /current/directory/path/
$
```

i.e. it has a line break in it.

If I activate a virtualenv, I would expect:

```
(myproject)[hugo] /current/directory/path/
$
```

But in fact I get no change at all.

I've opened up the `/bin/activate` script, and looked at the code:

```
if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="$PS1"
    else
    if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
        # special case for Aspen magic directories
        # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
        PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
    fi
    fi
    export PS1
fi
```

If I stick an echo in at the end, I can see the that the `PS1` var is set to `(myproject)[\u] \w \n\[\033[0;31m\]$\[\e[0m\]`, but for some reason that isn't sticking, and the correct PS1 is not being exported.

Is this something to do with my custom prompt, or a permissions issue? It's clearly **not** a virtualenv thing, as I know that it works (and in fact it works on my vagrant VM, just not on my OSX host).

?

**[UPDATE 1]**

My mistake - it looks like I have a git-aware prompt which is overwriting the prompt depending on the directory / repo status. This is what's killing the venv prompt. Now I just need one that does both - so, follow-up question is: does anyone have a colour, git-aware, OSX prompt that places nicely with virtualenv.

Comment: I was having the same problem, and found the solution in this article: https://cewing.github.io/training.codefellows/lectures/day01/shell.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whatever is setting up your git-aware prompt is probably defining the `PROMPT_COMMAND` function. Try adding this to the end of your `.bashrc` file.

```
add_venv_info () {
    if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
        _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"

        if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
            # special case for Aspen magic directories
            # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
            PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
        elif [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "" ]; then
            PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
        fi
    fi
    export PS1
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=add_venv_info
```

What are Aspen magic directories? I have no idea; this was code copied from an `activate` script to demonstrate how to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to include virtual environment information into your propmt. If they aren't relevant to your situation, you can simply add the `PS1=...` assignment that you want. The only really important parts are 1) Checking `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` and 2) making the desired assignment to `PS1`.

Comment: Likewise- had to fiddle a little to get it to work. Adding at end of .bashrc didn't work directly. Instead, I copy pasted this script (which is same as what's in "bin/activate" in virtualenv folder) directly below other prompt setup in .bashrc, but before export of PS1, and it worked.

Comment: I think there needs to be a semicolon added in the last line between $PROMPT_COMMAND and add_venv_info to make it work.

Comment: Amazing the errors that go unnoticed for 4+ years. :) However, I'm going to be lazy and assume `PROMPT_COMMAND` hasn't been set. Otherwise, you need to do extra work to ensure that you don't end up with a value like `; add_venv_info` or `make_my_prompt ;; add_venv_info`, both of which will causes errors.

Comment: What is `if [ "x" != x ]` supposed to do? When would this ever be true?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves I copied this code either from an existing `activate` script or some code that generated. It might be an artifact of the old trick `if [ "x$foo" != x] ]` to check if a variable is empty. Whatever the source, it's clearly unnecessary here; I'll clean up the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, but the above solution didn't work for me.

I ended up doing this:
*(mind that there's an additional space to separate the `(virtenv)` from the `$`*

```
# Virtual ENV stuff
add_venv_info () {
    if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
        VIRT_ENV_TXT=""
        if [ "x" != x ] ; then
            VIRT_ENV_TXT=""
        else
            if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
                # special case for Aspen magic directories
                # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
                VIRT_ENV_TXT="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``]"
            elif [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "" ]; then
                VIRT_ENV_TXT="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)"
            fi
        fi
        if [ "${VIRT_ENV_TXT}" != "" ]; then
           echo ${VIRT_ENV_TXT}" "
        fi
    fi
}

# Now we construct the prompt.
# in my case a bunch of lines constructing the complete PS1
# somewhere call the add_venv_info function like below

        PS1=${PS1}"\[\$(job_color)\]\n\$(add_venv_info)\$\[${NC}\] "
```

Comment: you need to provide job_color

Comment: I had the same issue where the top answer didn't work for me. I've added your add_venv_info function into my prompt building function and it works prefectly, thanks.

Comment: Did the same thing as @TomDalton , works just fine! Note that the `if [ "x" != x ]` piece doesn't really serve a purpose and can be deleted.

Comment: I believe the x = x thing is to detect if you're using a bash-like shell.